# $\frac{1}{6}$ vs $\frac{5}{6}$ probability difference with 6 dice

Tags: probability, combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

Could somebody help me understand why there are

$\frac{1}{6}$ chance of rolling a 6 on a 6-sided die

$\frac{5}{6}$ chance of not rolling a 6 on a 6-sided die

However, when I try to compute the probability using $\frac{1}{6}$ and its complement $\frac{5}{6}$ for 6 dice, the numbers don't add up?

Probability of rolling a 6 with 6 dice = $\frac{1}{6} \cdot \frac{1}{6} \cdot \frac{1}{6} \cdot \frac{1}{6} \cdot \frac{1}{6} \cdot \frac{1}{6}  = \frac{1}{6}^6$

Probability of not rolling a 6 with 6 dice = $\frac{5}{6} \cdot \frac{5}{6} \cdot \frac{5}{6} \cdot \frac{5}{6} \cdot \frac{5}{6} \cdot \frac{5}{6} = \frac{5}{6}^6$

I couldn't understand why the probability for $\frac{1}{6}^6$ and it's complement $1 - \frac{5}{6}^6$ is not the same.

Kindly advise.

Comment: @drhab, thank you for the reply. could you expand on what you meant? what is the complement of not rolling a 6 with 6 dices; vice versa.

Comment: The first computation represents the probability of getting all 6's.  The second computation represents the probability of getting all non-6's.  The reason that these $2$ probabilities do not sum to $1$ is that these are not the only possibilities.  That is, if you roll $6$ dice, there are $7$ mutually exclusive events, where the probabilities of these $7$ events will sum to $1$.  The $7$ events are having exactly $k$ of the $6$ dice come up a $6$, where $k$ is some element in $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}.$

Comment: See also [Binomial Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution), 
specifically $\displaystyle \binom{n}{k}p^kq^{(n-k)}.$

Comment: The complement of not rolling a six with 6 dice is: rolling "at least one six" with 6 dice (so not"exactly 6 sixes").

Comment: Pay attention to your phrasing: in your Question, when you write “probability of rolling a 6 with six dices”, do you see that it would have been more accurate (or at least less ambiguous) to write “probability of rolling ***six*** 6’s with 6 dice” instead? After all, the outcome ‘222622’ does mean that you have “rolled a 6 with six dice”, right?

Comment: @ryang, thank you for the reply. i've being thrown off with the wording with combinatorics and set theory related problems. Thankful to have access here for clarification.

Comment: @ManOnTheMoon Glad to be of help! These issues are indeed tricky; I like to re-read my sentences and check for ways to mis-interpret my intended meaning (or for how my unclear phrasing may obfuscate my own reasoning); using the same example: "probability of rolling a 6 with six dices” sounds like it implicitly has an "at least" between "of rolling" and "a 6".

Comment: Die is singular; dice is plural; dices is the third person singular form of the verb to dice, meaning to cut into small cubes.  Compliment means praise (when used as a noun) or to praise (when used as a verb); the complement of a subset $A \subseteq S$ is the set of elements in $S$ that are not in $A$.

Comment: @ N. F. Taussig, thank you for the correction, I've corrected the title too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $6$ dice are thrown then the following prescribed events are mutually exclusive but are not covering (so are not complements of eachother):

- $A$: Each of the $6$ rolls results in a six. Here $P(A)=\left(\frac16\right)^6$
- $B$: None of the $6$ rolls results in a six. Here $P(B)=\left(\frac56\right)^6$

It is quite well possible that both events do not occur. For instance if exactly $2$ dice result in a six.

We do have $A\cap B=\varnothing$ but not $A\cup B=\Omega$ (or equivalently $B=A^{\complement}$).

For completeness:

- $A^c$: At least one of the $6$ rolls does not result in a six.
- $B^c$: At least one of the $6$ rolls results in a six.